# How to configure qmake to save *.obj in subdirectories?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have problem with build configuration.I get 'LNK2019' error:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Reference::Item::Item(void)" (??0Item@Object@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main

Filesystem structure for my project look like this (World.pro):

```
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        Window.cpp \
    Item.cpp \
    Object/Item.cpp \
    Reference/Item.cpp

HEADERS += \
        Window.h \
    Item.h \
    Object/Item.h \
    Reference/Item.h
```

I know where problem lay. Currently compiler save output files in one main directory, hence there will be 3 files with the same name (currently they are overwritten?), that's why linker cant find proper files.
How to ask kindly compiler to save *.obj in proper subdirectories 'Object', 'Reference', and inform linker where to search for this files?

I don't want separate project to sub-projects (libraries). I happy with current filesystem structure. Also naming conversion is perfect for me, I like refer to types by `Object::Item` and `Reference::Item`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can tweak qmake build system, as when reading the doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#objects-dir  here, it does not seem that you have any possibility to define specific folders per source directory.

For me this is a bad practice to have files with same name in the same project. It only leads to confusion.

I looks like you are making a confusion between file names and namespaces :

You can very well obtain the same result with different files names ( Reference/ReferenceItem.h) , because how you name the classes in C++ is not related to file name, it is only a convention (to have class Foobar in a file Foobar.h/.cpp)

=> You can have two classes with the same name if they are not in the same namespace. The file name has no impact on it.

> Reference/ReferenceItem.h file

```
namespace reference {
  class Item {
   //implementation here...
  }
}
```

> Object/ObjectItem.h

```
namespace object {
  class Item {
   //implementation here...
  }
}
```